# How do you get html content from Apache httpclient on error?

Tags: java, http

I am using Apache http client in java but am noticing the it refuses to get content on non 200 results... How do I override it?

Comment: There very of is no content to get for non-200 return codes. Are you certain you should be getting any?

Comment: 100% positive I need it to act like curl does, return the content on error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

import java.io.*;

public class HttpClientTutorial {

  private static String url = "http://www.apache.org/";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an instance of HttpClient.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Create a method instance.
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    // Provide custom retry handler is necessary
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
      }

      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

      // Deal with the response.
      // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
      System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

    } catch (HttpException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Release the connection.
      method.releaseConnection();
    }  
  }
}
```

on the 200 and 404 and it works as expected (error code + content). The code is from apache website itself: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

Comment: I suggest going to HttpClient 4.x.